# Render Error : undefined is not an object (evaluating"itineraries[index].places)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const index: any = Object.keys(itineraries)[0];
    setSelectedItinerary(itineraries[index].places as ItineraryPlace[]);
    setSelectedDay(index);
    () => setSelectedItinerary([]);
  }, [itineraries]);
```

[Render Error Undefined line 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWN3M.jpg)

It works well at first when creating the first user but after that it displays the error. If I restart the app, the problem repeats as what it occurs. I have tried looking what could go wrong in the code but I have no idea what causes the error.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve so that members can help and  return () => setSelectedItinerary([]); doesn't look right even if its a cleanup, is should cause a rerender
n try putting  some more checks itineraries[index]?.places ?? []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itineraries` might be empty or null. use `?` (optional) operator to chain the nested items

```
 setSelectedItinerary(itineraries?.[index]?.places as ItineraryPlace[]);
```

Comment: Hi! It is now working and doesn't cause render error. Thank you so much!